# What are a few alternative ways to say "to expect"?

Tags: mandarin, usage, word-requests

There are many situations I'd like to say the following in Chinese:

- "That phone call was unexpected"
- "I did not expect that meeting to be so difficult"

The only approach I know of is:

- "我没想到那个电话“
- ”我没想到那个会议会是哪么难“

I know you can also use 突然, but it's not quite parallel. The best way I can think of applying it in this situation is:

- 那个电话突然来了

Appreciate anyone's thoughts on this!

Thanks

Comment: I think you have a good **colloquial** handle of this already

Answer (score 2):

不可预知的情况 not can predict situation = an unexpected situation
出乎意料的形势 unexpected circumstance
不意外 not unexpected
意外 unexpected
竟然 unexpected

’那个打过来的电话是意料之外的。‘ 或者 ‘没想到那个电话会打过来。’
That phone call was unexpected.

会议比我预料中的难很多。
The meeting was much more difficult than I expected.

Comment: Thank you also for your response. I had not considered 不可预知 as another approach. Is this a more formal phrasing than "没想到？"

Comment: Not really suitable in your context.